# Both pipe and redirecting exist in shell

Tags: shell, pipe, io-redirection

How to explain the output of `cat /etc/passwd | cat </etc/issue`?

In this case, the second `cat` receives contents from `/etc/passwd` as `$STDIN` and again `/etc/issue` is redirected. Why there is only `/etc/issue` left?

What's more, `cat </etc/passwd </etc/issue` only outputs the contents in `/etc/issue`. Is `/etc/passwd` overwritten?

I am not looking for a solution how to `cat` two files, but confused with how `pipeline` works.

Answer (score 3):

Piping and redirection are processed from left to right.

So first the input of `cat` is redirected to the pipe. Then it is redirected to `/etc/issue`. Then the program is run, using the last redirection, which is the file.

When you do `cat <file1 <file2`, stdin is first redirected to `file1`, then it is redirected to `file2`. Then the program is run, and it gets its input from the last redirection.

It's like variable assignments. If you do:

```
stdin=passwd
stdin=issue
```

The value of `stdin` at the end is the last one assigned.

This is explained in the `bash` documentation, in the first paragraph of the section on [Redirection](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections):

> Before a command is executed, its input and output may be *redirected* using a special notation interpreted by the shell. Redirection may also be used to open and close files for the current shell execution environment. The following redirection operators may precede or appear anywhere within a simple command or may follow a command. Redirections are processed in the order they appear, **from left to right**.

(emphasis mine). I assume it's also in the POSIX shell specification, I haven't bothered to look it up. This is how Unix shells have always behaved.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Can you give some details (proof) why it behaves this way? For example, where can I find a rule stating that `Piping and redirection are processed from left to right.`?

Comment: I've copied the section of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The pipe is created first: the standard output of `cat /etc/passwd` is sent to write side of the pipe, and the standard input of `cat </etc/issue` is set to the read side of the pipe.  Then the command on each half of the pipe is processed.  There's no other I/O redirection on the LHS, but on the RHS, the standard input is redirected so it comes from `/etc/issue`.  That means there's nothing actually reading the read end of the pipe, so the LHS `cat` is terminated with a SIGPIPE (probably; alternatively, it writes data to the pipe but no process ever reads it).  The LHS `cat` never knows about the pipe input — it only has the the file input for its standard input.